# 2 dimensional array PHP

Tags: php, arrays

I'm pretty new to php and I have problem with 2 dimentional array. When I try to do this:

```
$tab[0][0] = "dupa0";
$tab[0][1] = "dupa1";
echo("$tab[0][0]");
```

It doesn't work. How can I print a single element from this array?

Comment: Remove the double quotes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to remove the quotes:

```
echo($tab[0][0]);
```

Comment: *im assuming that $tab[0] is already an array* It will be silently created with `$tab[0][0] = "dupa0";` if it isn't already one

Comment: Or assuming that this needs to be used in double quotes `echo("{$tab[0][0]}");`